# Sincronizar datos de base de datos con google calendar

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, google-calendar

Tengo un tabla de tareas donde se tiene: fecha de inicio, hora de inicio, fecha fin y hora fin, también la tarea que hay que realizar con una descripción.

Ahora implemente un calendario de google y lo que quiero hacer que no puedo, es reflejar esas tareas en dicho calendario.

Me olvide de aclarar, estoy utilizando el framework laravel.

Comment: ¿en que plataforma? Para Android se como crear eventos en un calendar

Comment: Laravel-php!. Me olvide de mencionar eso

Comment: entonces no puedo serte de ayuda, no tengo experiencia con esa plataforma. Espero que tengas suerte

Comment: Una búsqueda simple en Google arroja como resultado varios proyectos en GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones, Javascript desde el lado cliente o PHP si quieres hacerlo desde el servidor.

En ambos casos es realizar un POST a su API para insertar un evento, aquí debajo tienes un enlace con la documentación oficial.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert